# Update for iPod touch 3rd generation

Tags: wifi

Hi I have a pretty tough question it's because all my friends text with imessage and I feel kinda left out is there a way ANY WAY that I could get imessage on my iPod touch 3G     There is this boy at my school that has it on his touch 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get iOS 5 on iPod Touch 3G, which includes the iMessage application. However,  make sure that you truly have an iPod Touch 3G and not an iPod Touch 2G, which can only be updated to iOS 4.2.1. According to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) from Wikipedia, iPod Touch 3G can go up to iOS 5.1.1.